# Small question regarding Hadamard matrix of order $4m$

Tags: combinatorial-designs, hadamard-matrices

I am curious about something after reading stuff about Hadamard matrix conjecture.

What I understand is that all of the $4m$ rows are orthogonal.
Is it possible that for some $m$ such that the Hadamard matrix $H$ of order $4m$ exists, there is an additional row vector orthogonal to the rows of $H$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, because $HH^{T} = nI$ which implies that the rows are all linearly independent (and so $H$ will have a nontrivial kernel).

Comment: @MorganRodgers Ah, I see. Then these n rows exactly span $\mathbb{R}_n$, so there is no more orthogonal row. Correct?